# Tomcat + Hibernate - can't persist any data

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, postgresql-9.3

I have a problem with my new app. It's webapp with JAX-RS REST API, I have placed it on Tomcat 9.

Everything was good, my app can fetch data from localhost database (PSQL). I don't know why, but when i want to persist data -> it's returning me no error at all, but there is no mark after persisting data on database.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
@Path("/register")
public Response register(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password,
                         @FormParam("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber) {

    UserEntity newUser = new UserEntity();
    newUser.setEmail(email);
    newUser.setPassword(password);
    newUser.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    newUser.setEntryDate(new Date());

    AuthorizationDAO.put(newUser);
```

and DAO method:

```
public static <T extends AbstractTechnicalEntity> void put(T entity) {
    em.persist(entity);
}
```

It's not a problem with connection - as I said, I can select data from this database, even from this table.

persistence.xml - > database conf

```
<properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/*****" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="******" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: and I wonder what the JPA providers log says ?

Comment: How you configured EntityManager/transaction ? if manually than you  need to call .commit

Comment: Hey! You were right, I have to manually begin and then commit transaction! Thanks for help